# Connection Strings- smarterasp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, deployment, connection

Can anyone help me with this? Ive been getting tons of errors. I know there's probably just a syntax error here somewhere, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

this is the connection string that was given to me by smarterasp: "Data Source=SQL5006.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B7F44_capstone;User Id=DB_9B7F44_capstone_admin;Password=YOUR-PASSWORD;"

this was my connection string on my local machine:

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="d_CapstoneEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-C43BMU8UF5E\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=d_Capstone;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

and then I came up with this, but im still getting the error "Keyword not supported: 'data source'."

```
<add name="d_CapstoneEntities1" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5006.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B7F44_capstone;User Id=DB_9B7F44_capstone_admin;Password=YOUR-PASSWORD;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"/></connectionStrings>
```

I used the EF database first btw.